# TinyMCE 5 editor not showing any dropdown Item

Tags: javascript, tinymce-4, tinymce-5

I was working with TinyMCE 4, it was working good but I moved to TinyMCE 5, it started creating issues.
When I click any drop-down menu it doesn't show any menu item e.g if I click on the "Paragraph" drop down it is not displaying any menu item. All other buttons are working fine(that are not drop-down) e.g bold, italic etc.

[image: TinyMCE on my website]

When I click any drop-down menu it doesn't show any error, I checked the console many times.

[image: Console when clicking drop-down menu]

**Official document link**: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/basic-setup/

If you go to the bottom of this document, you'll see it show codepen link, there code is working fine i.e drop-down menu are working fine, I'm using the same js code but still drop-down menu is not working for me. I'm not able to understand what the issue can be.

**My code:-**

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    width: 600,
    height: 300,
    plugins: [
      'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
      'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking',
      'table emoticons template paste help'
    ],
    toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | ' +
      'bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | print preview media fullpage | ' +
      'forecolor backcolor emoticons | help',
    menu: {
      favs: {title: 'My Favorites', items: 'code visualaid | searchreplace | emoticons'}
    },
    menubar: 'favs file edit view insert format tools table help',
    content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }'
  });
```

Any help will be appreciated, **Thanks**.

**PS:** I'm using bootstrap 4 but not using any kind of bootstrap modal.

Comment: It often has to do with positioning. The popup is there, just floating behind something, or positioned top/left 0px and out of sight because you scrolled a little down. Try checking the page's DOM using Inspect Element.

Comment: @JeffreyRoosendaal thanks for your time, I played with positioned but nothing happened. Seems like I'm stuck.

Comment: Quick question, do you have another 3rd party style library on your page? such as bootstrap4...

Comment: yes I'm using bootstrap 4

Comment: do you have some HTML examples? Do you locate the tinymce in Bootstrap modal? It seems there is some issue between Bootstrap Modal and TinyMce.

Comment: I'm not using any kind of modal, it's simple page having some form fields.

Comment: and you're right I also have seen that in some cases TinyMCE creates issues with bootstrap modal, but I'm not using any kind of bootstrap modal here. I'm using this TinyMCE on a simple page.

Comment: If I were you, I would try to remove the bootstrap4 library and test the Tinymce alone. If there is no issue after removing the bootstrap4, there may be some css style in bootstrap overwrite your tinymce style.

Comment: ley me try this.

Comment: I did but nothing happened :'(

Comment: Try very simple init like ```tinymce.init({selector: 'textarea'});```. Besides bootstrap4, do you have other css style? If so, they may affect the tinymce as well.

Comment: Thanks all for your help, one of my css file conflicting with it

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE adds a  tag at the end of your html body.
this div is for create lists of dropdown buttons you click...
so if you have multiple elements with different z-index, this may cause that div goes behind others and cant be seen...
so my solution which is not the best is:
add this code in setup option of TinyMCE init():

```
setup: function (ed) {
    ed.on('init', function () {                        
        $(".tox.tox-silver-sink.tox-tinymce-aux").css("z-index", 100000);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I put this css on my stylesheet. This works for all select options. My problem was i use bootstrap 5 and others libraries with css, the z-index value of TinyMCE was the problem.

```
.tox .tox-menu.tox-collection.tox-collection--list.tox-selected-menu {
    z-index: 100000 !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can resolve this by simply modifying the css.

```
.tox-tinymce-aux {               
      z-index: 130000000000 !important;
   
}
```